# Java 8 Using Stream, find the latest status, if 'F' replace the reason from the corresponding from status 'R'

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream, grouping

I have a List of Object with field names as below, I'm trying to replace the reason field of the 
status 'F' from the corresponding reason field from status 'R'. This needs to be performed only when the latest status by timestamp per publisher has a status of 'F'

```
auditedBy   status    time        Reason 
api-a         S        10:20       'A1'
api-a         R        10:25       'A2'
api-a         F        10:30       'A3' 
-----
api-b         S        10:30       'B1'
api-b         S        10:25       'B2'
api-b         S        10:20       'B3'
-----
api-c         S        10:20       'C1' 
api-c         S        10:30       'C1'
api-c         F        10:40       'C3'
```

so the final output of the above data will be

```
auditedBy   status    time        Reason 
api-a         S        10:20       'A1'
api-a         R        10:25       'A2'
api-a         F        10:30       'A2' ******

api-b         S        10:30       'B1'
api-b         S        10:25       'B2'
api-b         S        10:20       'B3'

api-c         S        10:20       'C1' 
api-c         S        10:30       'C1'
api-c         F        10:40       'C3'
```

I'll provide my implementation below please let me know if any improvements is needed.

1. I'll create map with the latest status as 'F' 
   Map will have

   > api-a    ->   api-a,F,10:30,'A3'
   >   api-c    ->   api-c,F,10:40,'C3'
2. Then I'll create map, this will contain records
   with status as 'R' for those records in previous map.
   Map above will have.

   > api-a    ->   api-a,R,10:25,'A2'
3. I'll change the reason from the original list from both the maps.

```java
    private List<DetailRecord> changeReasonFunction(List<DetailRecord> records) {
        Map<String, DetailRecord> eventsFailed = records.stream()
                .collect(toMap(DetailRecord::getAuditedBy, Function.identity(),                      
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(DetailRecord::getAuditTimestamp))))
                .values()
                .stream().filter(detRec -> FAILED.getStatus().equals(detRec.getStatus()))
                .collect(toMap(DetailRecord::getAuditedBy, Function.identity()));

        Map<String, DetailRecord> retryRecordForFailedEvents = records.stream()
                .filter(rec -> eventsFailed.keySet().contains(rec.getAuditedBy()))
                .filter(rec -> FAILED_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.getStatus().equals(rec.getStatus()))
                .collect(toMap(DetailRecord::getAuditedBy, Function.identity(), 
                 BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(DetailRecord::getAuditTimestamp))));

        records.forEach(rec -> {
            if (eventsFailed.containsKey(rec.getAuditedBy()) && 
                    eventsFailed.get(rec.getAuditedBy()).getAuditTimestamp()
                    .compareTo(rec.getAuditTimestamp()) == 0) {
                DetailRecord obj = retryRecordForFailedEvents.get(rec.getAuditedBy());
                if (obj != null) {
                    rec.setExceptionReason(obj.getExceptionReason());
                    rec.setExceptionDetail(obj.getExceptionDetail());
                }
            }
        });

        return records;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with `groupingBy` collector like this:

```
private List<DetailRecord> changeReasonFunction(List<DetailRecord> records) {
    return records.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DetailRecord::getAuditedBy))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(list -> {
                Optional<DetailRecord> maxRecord = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(DetailRecord::getTime));
                if (maxRecord.isPresent()
                        && maxRecord.get().getStatus().equals("F")
                        && list.stream().anyMatch(detailRecord -> detailRecord.getStatus().equals("R"))) {
                    maxRecord.get().setReason(
                            list.stream()
                                    .filter(detailRecord -> detailRecord.getStatus().equals("R"))
                                    .findAny().get().getReason());
                }
                return list.stream();
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You'll need to modify it based on the datatypes you are using. I used:

```
public class DetailRecord {

    private String auditedBy;
    private String status;
    private Instant time;
    private String reason;
}
```

Test:

```
List<DetailRecord> l = new ArrayList<>();

l.add(new DetailRecord("api-a", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:20:00.00Z"), "A1"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-a", "R", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:25:00.00Z"), "A2"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-a", "F", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:30:00.00Z"), "A3"));

l.add(new DetailRecord("api-b", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:30:00.00Z"), "B1"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-b", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:25:00.00Z"), "B2"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-b", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:20:00.00Z"), "B3"));

l.add(new DetailRecord("api-c", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:20:00.00Z"), "C1"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-c", "S", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:30:00.00Z"), "C1"));
l.add(new DetailRecord("api-c", "F", Instant.parse("2019-01-01T10:40:00.00Z"), "C3"));

System.out.println(changeReasonFunction(l));
```

Output is as you expected.

Comment: thanks @kartik it took a while to understand ur solution, I ran it locally with my code and it working good. I did a small change from
`list.stream().anyMatch(detailRecord -> detailRecord.getStatus().equals("R"))) {
                    maxRecord.get().setReason`
to 
`list.stream()
.filter(detailRecord -> detailRecord.getStatus().equals("R")))
.max(comparing(DetailRecord::getTime));` 
for the latest one, there could be multiple with status 'R' I forgot to add to my question.

Comment: @krrish0690 Sorry, I should have explained more. Let me know if anything is not clear and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asume the same `DetailRecord` class as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279114/11733759).

At the beginning we have grouped inputList based on `auditedBy`

```java
Map<String, List<DetailRecord>> groupByCollection = inputList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DetailRecord::getAuditedBy));
```

Now on every list we can make substitution. List is sorted, in reduce method there is searching for the first record with `status` "R". If it is found, it is preserved and searching is continue for record with `status` "F", if it is found the substitution is made.

```java
groupByCollection.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(DetailRecord::getTime))
      .reduce(null, (DetailRecord a, DetailRecord v) -> {
          if (a == null && v.getStatus().equals("R")) {
              return v;
          }
          if (a != null  && v.getStatus().equals("F")) {
              v.setReason(a.getReason());
          }
          return a;
      }, (a1, a2) -> a1)
);

groupByCollection.entrySet()
      .forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream().forEach(System.out::println));
```

Example init list code:

```java
List<String> inputStrings = Arrays.asList(
      "api-a         S        10:20       'A1'",
      "api-a         R        10:25       'A2'",
      "api-a         F        10:30       'A3'",
      "api-b         S        10:30       'B1'",
      "api-b         S        10:25       'B2'",
      "api-b         S        10:20       'B3'",
      "api-c         S        10:20       'C1'",
      "api-c         S        10:30       'C1'",
      "api-c         F        10:40       'C3'"
);

List<DetailRecord> inputList = inputStrings.stream()
      .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
      .map(s -> new DetailRecord(s[0], s[1], Instant.parse("2019-01-01T" + s[2] + ":00.00Z"), s[3].replaceAll("'", "")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```